# How to find an index of a string(first three character) from an array

Tags: c#, .net

I want to find an index of a string only for first three char from an array

I have an array of month

```
string[] arrayEnglishMonth = { "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER" };
```

If I write

```
     int t_ciMonth=8;(AUGUST)
     int pos = Array.IndexOf(t_caMonth, arrayEnglishMonth[t_ciMonth - 1]);
```

But if I want the Index for only first 3 character i.e AUG how to find it?

Comment: You mean you want to find the index of the first string in the array that starts with a given string, e.g. "AUG"?

Comment: You do know about [DateTimeFormatInfo.GetMonthName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx) and [DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatedmonthname.aspx)?

Comment: yes..............................

Comment: @Proneet, what is `t_caMonth`?

Comment: Is that some sort of C variable naming convention?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici its interger value 8 so I get the month August(user input month=8)

Comment: `t_caMonth`, not `t_ciMonth`

Comment: Okay, so you have your array, and the input "AUG" and you want to get 8, right? This should do it: `arrayEnglishMonth.TakeWhile(s => !s.StartsWith("AUG")).Count() + 1;`

Comment: @Corak Actually I want to find that at what index the August or Aug appears in the other array i.e t_caMonth

Comment: @Proneet, check the alternatives in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options I can think of:

1. `Linq` only aproach that looks like this:

   ```
   var index = arrayEnglishMonth.Select((v, i) => new { v, i })
                                .Where(c => c.v.StartsWith("AUG"))
                                .Select(c => c.i)
                                .First();
   ```

   This will first iterate over existing array, create enumerable of anonymous objects holding values and indexes, where predicate passed in `Where` returns true, after that select only index and take the first element from enumerable.

   [Demo](http://ideone.com/Eofshi)
2. Find respective month using `Linq` and then use `IndexOf` method:

   ```
   var item = arrayEnglishMonth.First(c => c.StartsWith("AUG"));
   var index = Array.IndexOf(arrayEnglishMonth, item);
   ```

   [Demo](http://ideone.com/7Z3dxo)

Comment: Where do you use `t_caMonth` in your answer? Take a more attentive look to the code in the question.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici As far as I understood question OP was stuck with finding index in `arrayEnlishMonth`. Once s/he has index it's not a big deal to check if that index exists in another array.

Comment: Regarding 1, it's doing something else: There's only 1 iteration over the array, for each element, an anonymous object is created and if it starts with AUG, its second element is returned.

Comment: @ytoledano Yeah, you are right. `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator` will be used for iteration over array. I'll update answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
arrayEnglishMonth.ToList().FindIndex(s => s.Substring(0,3) == "AUG");
```

Comment: looks elegant but I wonder what happens if the iteration reaches to the end of the list.. s.Substring(0,3) will not yield exception for out of range?

Comment: Why is this an answer if he's not looking into the `arrayEnglishMonth`, but in the `t_caMonth` array?

Comment: @G.Y. reaches the end as in it doesn't find a match? -1 is returned

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a little Linq:

```
string[] arrayEnglishMonth = { "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER" };
string[] t_caMonth = { ... };
string search = arrayEnglishMonth[7].Substring(0, 3); // "AUG";
int pos = t_caMonth
    .Select((s, i) => new { s, i }).Dump()
    .Where(x => x.s == search)
    .Select(x => x.i)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First();
```

Or more simply:

```
int pos = t_caMonth.TakeWhile(s => s != search).Count();
```

Although this last solution will return `t_caMonth.Length` instead of `-1` if no matching element is found.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici t_caMonth is an array which I get at run time

Comment: @p.s.w.g I want to get index from an array t_caMonth not the count

Comment: @Proneet Sorry I misunderstood what you were looking for. I've updated my answer. However, the `Count` in the second example doesn't do what you think it does. `TakeWhile(...).Count()` iterates through the list on til it finds an element that doesn't meet the condition (in this case, until it finds an a string that equals `search`) and then returns the number of items it had to go through until it found one--i.e. the index of the first match.

Answer (score 0):

If the `t_caMonth` has upper casing and it's values have only 3 letters, you may use:

```
 int pos = Array.IndexOf(t_caMonth, arrayEnglishMonth[t_ciMonth - 1]
     .Substring(0,3));
```

In order to manage casing and values with more than 3 characters, you could have:

```
var pos = -1;
var sel = t_caMonth
    .Select((i, index) => new { index, i = i.ToUpper() })
    .Where(i => 
        i.i.Substring(0,3) == arrayEnglishMonth[t_ciMonth - 1].Substring(0, 3))
    .Select(i => i.index);
if (sel.Count() > 0)
    pos = sel.FirstOrDefault();
```

You may also create a `List<string>` from your `t_caMonth` array:

```
var pos2 = t_caMonth
    .ToList()
    .FindIndex(i => 
        i.ToUpper().Substring(0, 3) == 
            arrayEnglishMonth[t_ciMonth - 1].Substring(0, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mine way to achieve this

```
string[] arrayEnglishMonth = { "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER" };
var searcheditem = arrayEnglishMonth.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Substring(0, 3) == "AUG");
if(searcheditem != null)
var itemIndex = Array.IndexOf(arrayEnglishMonth, searcheditem);
```

but @wdavo answer is better

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following, i think it is the fastest
`Array.FindIndex(strArray, s => s.StartsWith("AUG"));`

Cheers.

Comment: why do ppl are so obsessed with linq that they forget there are simple functions to do the job for you :)